# Phone Number Masking (Without Plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask

I'm trying to do phone masking using the example in [this link](https://codepen.io/fdaciuk/pen/xdMwRw), but without success.What I want to do is remove the parentheses and reorder.

**Rule:** the first character is **always 5.**
In the form of 3 3 2 2, **example: 532 123 45 67**

```
const $input = document.querySelector('[data-js="input"]')
$input.addEventListener('input', handleInput, false)

function handleInput (e) {
  e.target.value = phoneMask(e.target.value)
}

function phoneMask (phone) {
  return phone.replace(/\D/g, '')
    .replace(/^(\d)/, '($1')
    .replace(/^(\(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1) $2')
    .replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1-$2")
    .replace(/(-\d{4})\d+?$/, '$1');
}
```

---

Sorry for misreporting blocks in the first post. No new character entry should be allowed upon completion.

The blocks will be as follows: **3 3 2 2 / Example : 532 123 45 67**

Comment: You mean, "remove the parentheses and _regroup_", not _reorder_, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex can be tricky but I love how nice is the result :)

```
function phoneMask (phone) {
  return phone.replace(/\D/g, '')
    .replace(/(^[^5])/, '')
    .replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1 $2')
    .replace(/(\d{3}\s\d{3})(\d{1,2})/, '$1 $2')
    .replace(/(\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{2})(\d{1,2})/, '$1 $2')
    .replace(/(\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{2})\d+?$/, '$1')
}
```

Explained steps:

1. To only allow numbers, replace non-digits with empty string: `.replace(/\D/g, '')`
2. Allow only 5 at the beginning, so replace first digit which isn't 5 by empty string:  `.replace(/(^[^5])/, '')`
3. Make 2 groups: the first with 3 digits and add a space between them:
   `.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1 $2')`
4. After having 3-space-3 digits, add another space between that group and the rest: `.replace(/(\d{3}\s\d{3})(\d{1,2})/, '$1 $2')`
5. After having 3-space-3-space-2 digits, add another space between that group and the rest: `.replace(/(\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{2})(\d{1,2})/, '$1 $2')`
6. Once the sequence 3-space-3-space-2-space-2-digits is completed, end string: `.replace(/(\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{2})\d+?$/, '$1')`

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help. But the number of blocks seems to be wrong.

I want the blocks to be like this : 3 3 2 2
Example: 532 123 45 67

Comment: Oh sorry, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way :

1- Remove any non-number character

2- Format the numbers as "3 4 2 2" (or any other way)

```
  phone = '+ (123) 45678901';
  phone = phone.replace(/[^0-9]+/gim, '');
  phone = phone.replace(/^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/, '$1 $2 $3 $4');
```